# Chebyshev Filter design using bilinear transformation-2 methods-2 transfer functions-which is right and which is wrong?

Tags: infinite-impulse-response

[image]
[image]
[image]

I got myself a book after looking the advice from stackexchange, it has been so far helpful for me. But I got confused in this numerical given in the book.

The other method is this-:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhoVH2wB9dc&t=1248s
But the answers from two methods are different. i.e the transfer function from these 2 processes are different. I am confused. Which is right and which is wrong.

Comment: The two analog t.f. have different frequency scalings applied. I didn't progress further from this point. The order formula could use a reference to its derivation. Also, while I'm sure for you this has good educational value, for a Q&A site, making people watch videos instead of extracting and writing down the needed information, can be tedious.

Comment: Just an idea: are you aware that they are two different types of Chebyshev filters and did you check that both methods design the same type ?